# Using View.getParent() in View's constructor

Tags: android, view

Why doesn't this work?

```
private ScrollView findScrollParent(View v)
{

    if(v==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if(v instanceof ScrollView)
    {
        return (ScrollView) v;
    }
    else
    {
        return findScrollParent((View)v.getParent());
    }
}

CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet as)
{
     super(context,as);
     ScrollView sv = findScrollParent(this);
}
```

This is my xml file which is inflated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

       <com.myapp.CustomView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to have a reference to the scrollView in the custom View. My findScrollParent method finds the `LinearLayout` then returns null. I call this method in the `View v`'s constructor, is that the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are calling it in the view's constructor then surely it will not have it's parent assigned yet?

As far as I can see from skimming the source the parent attribute is not set until the view is added to the parent at which point it will do something like:

```
child.mParent = this;
```

So if you are in the constructor for the view then my guess is it is too early and the view will be added after it is constructed. I was not 100% sure what combination of classes you were talking about / how you had them fitting together so may have looked at the wrong source.

EDIT

Just to clarify with pseudo code the process might look like this

```
View view = new View();  // Inside here you are calling your method - which won't work
addView(view);           // The parent is only just being set as a result of this method
view.getParent();        // At this point we can now return the expected result
```

EDIT 2 - @codelark 's suggestion

```
private _scrollView; // member variable

private ScrollView getScrollView()
{
   if (null == _scrollView) {
       _scrollView = findScrollParent(this);
   }
   return _scrollView;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... that makes sense. But why does the method find the LinearLayout parent? I added some code to show how I use the function.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, the View's are constructed/instantiated moving downward from the root view in a heirarchy. If the Views are constructed then have addView called on them, then my method should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve? Your custom view can not be added to a view group until it has been constructed therefore calling getParent in the constructor is too soon.

Comment: I've added some more detail, maybe that will help you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Where are you using the result of the method? When do you need a handle on the scrollView? Can you not grab it at a later point?

Comment: Instead of setting it in the constructor, you can lazily initialize it via a getter. That way, you won't try to use the reference until it is needed, which should be some time long after the parent attribute is set.

Comment: Thanks. Lazy initialization, I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 15):

You can safely access your parent in onAttachedToWindow() method.

See [View Life Cycle.](http://landenlabs.com/android/info/view-life-cycle/view-life-cycle.html)